# Having Trouble Linking my SASS to my HTML in Atom

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm looking to start coding in Atom and I am having trouble getting things started.  I can't seem to connect my `style.scss` to the `index.html`. This is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a square</h1>
<div class="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is what I have in my `style.scss` which when complied makes `style.min.css`

```html
//Variables
$lightblue: #b8fdfb;
//CSS
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: $lightblue;
}
```

[This is all that shows up in my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0NNx.png)

Comment: are you compiling your css? can you show your file structure? What are you using to host the files? URL?

Comment: This is what my flie structure looks like. [link](https://i.imgur.com/45Ejb1J.png)

Comment: _What are you using to host the files? URL?_  Please answer this too

Comment: The files are hosted on my local machine. I can't link out to it because it's a local server.

Comment: I understand, but i need to know if you are using subfolders (`localhost/my-project`) and if you are using Something like APACHE, node or just opening the HTML on browser.

Comment: Another question: how are you compiling your sass files? (what command)

Comment: *E:\Personal Projects\Atom\test* is the full directory for my files. I'm using SASS-auto-compile inside Atom to compile my files.

I'm using atom-live-server to host my local server to view my files. the actual url is *http://127.0.0.1:51311/*

Comment: try to change `<link rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:51311/style.min.css">`. Generally, this problem happens when the CSS file isn't loaded. Check if it is indeed loaded (see dev tools from your browser) and if it has the correct content (open on your editor and check if everything is ok on `style.min.css`)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot attach **SASS** to **HTML**. You first need to compile it first to **CSS** & then link it to your **HTML** using `<link>` tag in the header. Like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="style.min.css" />
```

You need a preprocessor to convert SASS into CSS. You can use many tools such as [**Webpack**](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader), [**Prepros**](https://prepros.io/), etc.

Have a look at this [**reference**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Using_Sass). Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, I'm linking to _style.min.css_ in my header, which I believe is the compiled _style.scss_.  I think

Comment: @TylerPolito `style.scss` compiles to `style.css`, you cannot link `scss` files directly to HTML. You need to compile it to `css` & then link it via `link` tag. Hope you get it.